# How to run nohup on boot while writing nohup.out to a selected directory

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron, nohup, cloud-init

Im going to have to run a nohup command that will run for months and generate tons of logs, so I want to write the nohup.out file to a directory that contains the rest of the code.
My simple script to execute on every startup is:

```
sudo su ubuntu
cd /home/ubuntu/folder
nohup /home/ubuntu/folder/start_server.sh&
```

If I do a crontab job that runs the script, all of the nohup logs still go into `/var/log/syslog`.

If I do the same with cloud-init since im working on ec2, all logs into `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`.

How can I make nohup run in a choosen directory (`/home/ubuntu/folder` in my case) only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to run crontab with my starting script running `nohup /home/ubuntu/folder/start_server.sh > nohup.out` instead of just `nohup /home/ubuntu/folder/start_server.sh&`